# Field types database design best practice

Tags: database-design, eav, subtypes

I am creating a cms system where the user can create fields to use in the templates of the website. I want to create different types like 'string', 'html', 'integer' etc. The user must also have the possibility to add these fields in different values, so I will be needing at least two tables.

My question is this: Should I create a table for each field value type and catch this in the code or should I store all field value types in one table?

**Option 1:**
Table for each type

```
+---------------+    +-----------------+    +--------------------+
| Fields        |    | field_int_value |    | field_string_value |    etc...
+---------------+    +-----------------+    +--------------------+
| id            |    | field_id        |    | field_id           |
| field_type_id |    | language_id     |    | language_id        |
+---------------+    | value (int)     |    | value (varchar)    |
                     +-----------------+    +--------------------+
```

**Option 2:**
Store all values in one table. keep the unused values `NULL`.

```
+---------------+    +-----------------+
| Fields        |    | field_value     |
+---------------+    +-----------------+
| id            |    | field_id        |
| field_type_id |    | language_id     |
+---------------+    | value_int       |
                     | value_string    |
                     | etc...          |
                     +-----------------+
```

**Some examples:**

A user could for example create a string with his or her phone number. In the code the template would call this field to display the phone number. If the user would ever change this, they can just edit the value in the admin without having to worry about editing the template.

Another example is a boolean to allow the user to show a certain 'call to action' on a page. This boolean would be used to hide something in the template without having to update the template.

My Field model would be the one handling all this. In here I would create functions to get the field of a specific type.

---

I have been breaking my head over what would be the best option, but I can't seem to find the better one. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is an EAV data model where users defines the structue. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model I'd suggest you don't use an RDBMS for such unstructured data.

Comment: In Postgres you could use a `hstore` column for dynamic attributes. Much more efficient than the EAV pattern

Comment: Another helpful link concerning EAV: https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway

Answer (score 3):

Not discounting @gbn's suggestion (in a comment on the question) to possibly store this data somewhere other than in a RDBMS, I will say that if you do decide to go the RDBMS route, you are better off using a single table with a column per each "type" such that they can be strongly-typed. Or, you *could* use a single table with a single string field as all data can be converted/serialized to a string, but then you have to be careful to do the conversion properly in both directions for all operations, and that might prove problematic if some uses of that table either incorrectly convert or forget to convert altogether.

The reason for choosing a single table is mostly logistics: it is far easier to dynamically select a different column based on a COALESCE or CASE (or CASE-like) clause than it is to dynamically pull from different tables in a query based on the TypeID of the row (at least not without having to LEFT JOIN all "type" tables in all queries (yikes!).

Depending on which RDBMS you are using, there might even be vendor-specific features to assist in this model. For example, SQL Server, starting in version 2008, I believe, has a `SPARSE` option that can be added to NULLable columns. This allows for a NULL value to take up 0 bytes whereas normally, for fixed-length fields (i.e. pretty much all of them that aren't `[N]VAR{something}` or `{something} VARYING` or `XML` or generically `text` or `SQL_VARIANT`), they would always take up their specified number of bytes. The downside is that for non-NULL values, they now take up 4 extra bytes per row. But it can be a *huge* savings when the column is 75% or more NULL across all rows. This feature was designed specifically to address this type of model.

Just make sure to have a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` to ensure that for all of the `value_` fields, either none, or only one, of them is `NOT NULL`.

Then you can access via something like:

```
COALESCE(value_int, value_string, value_datetime, etc.)
```

And again, if you are using SQL Server (and maybe one or more other vendors have this feature), you can make use of "filtered indexes" to index each specific `value_` field where that value is not null:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FieldValues_ValueInt]
  ON dbo.[FieldValues] ([ValueInt])
  WHERE [ValueInt] IS NOT NULL;
```

This will allow you to target rows that do have values, although probably not when using the generic `COALESCE` access method, but when targeting a specific `Value%` field.

AND, looking again at the two options, I would actually go with **Option 3**, which is a single table. In **Option 2** it does not seem like there is much purpose in breaking `field_type_id` out as that data is not really a parent to the `field_value` data. A `field_id` can only have a single value, right? So just put `field_type_id` in the `field_value` table. And make use of it in the CHECK CONSTRAINT that ensures a single field at most is NOT NULL, to ensure that the one field, if any, that is NOT NULL matches the `field_type_id`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your options 1 and 2 looks like the difference between Class Table Inheritance and Single Table Inheritance.  These are two different ways of mimicking inheritance in table design.  If you want to explore the trade offs between the two techniques, I suggest you look up Martin Fowler's treatment of the subject.

You can see a summary of them [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html) and [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html).

You may also want to add this tag to your question, in order to get more answers.
[subtypes](/questions/tagged/subtypes)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a best design but I have been under the covers on a few and they went with separate tables for each datatype.  And even separate tables for single-value versus multi-value.

I would certainly go with multiple tables.  You have to select a column name or table name / join so not really much more complex. Can even use a view. An update takes a more specific lock.

Consider multi-value. What if you want to support email to both joe and sue.  A specific table is overhead but it is hard to do a lot of stuff with a simple data model.

There is spec out there you should consider supporting [CMIS](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/os/CMIS-v1.1-os.html). 
Clearly you don't have to support the spec but if you want interoperability that is the way to go.

But also have some players that don't support CMIS and have a document (no SQL) type  back end.

There is some great free open source CMS out there.